# OpenCV Python calcHist

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to calculate **`image histogram with OpenCV's calcHist function with Python`**.
 But it doesn't work.

Code:

`im = cv2.imread(imPath,0)
 hist = cv2.calcHist([im],[0],None,[256],[0,256])`

And I get **error** like this:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (step(dims[-1] == (size_t) CV_ELEM_SIZE(flags)) 
in create, file opencv/sources/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp line:236
```

Comment: The guy in that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390592/drawing-histogram-in-opencv-python calls it like that: `cv2.calcHist([item],[0],None,[256],[0,255])`. Note that the last list is `[0,255]` not `[0,256]`. Maybe that's your error? Would make sense..

Comment: ^^ I don't Callahan is correct. I think it is probably that your image is not reading in properly or the wrong file type.

Comment: @Callahan I run code again with your modification. But I got same error.

Comment: @GPPK image file extension is "BMP". Is that a problem?

Comment: shouldn't think so, but test it with a jpg to see?

Comment: I tested with jpg and the result is same.

Comment: In my experience, most of the time `imread()` does not work as expected. So you should verify that `im` is actually well defined after `imread()`.

Comment: I print im after read it and there is no problem. May this problem is about version of OpenCV ? Because, I tried the same code at another computer that has different version of opencv. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread(r'd:\temp\1.bmp',0)
hist = cv2.calcHist([im],[0],None,256,[0,255])

print im
print hist
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not incorrect - here is some example code that does the same thing ([taken from here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_begins/py_histogram_begins.html)):

```
img = cv2.imread('home.jpg',0)
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
```

Therefore I think your imPath is probably incorret. I would suggest using static file path, something similar to "C:\myImage.jpg", to start with and see if an error appears with that.